# SOAP with simplexml

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I am trying to access the 'code' element of the below xml, using simplexml, and experiencing an error.

```
$response = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
      <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Invalid Request. Please refer to detail section for more information</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ns1:HpiSoapFault xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.hpi.co.uk/SupplementaryEnquiryV1">
          <ns1:Error>
            <ns1:Code>012</ns1:Code>
            <ns1:Description>VRM is invalid</ns1:Description>
          </ns1:Error>
        </ns1:HpiSoapFault>
      </detail>
    </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$xml = @simplexml_load_string($response);

$soap_fault = $xml->children('soapenv', true)
                  ->Body->children('soapenv', true)
                  ->Fault->children('soapenv', true)
                  ->detail->children('ns1', true)
                  ->HpiSoapFault
                  ->Error 
                  ->Code;
```

This prints error:
Warning:  Node no longer exists in /home/xxx/xxx/test.php on line yyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

detail doesn't have namespace soapenv

```
$soap_fault = $xml->children('soapenv', true)
              ->Body->children('soapenv', true)
              ->Fault->children() // no namespace
              ->detail->children('ns1', true)
              ->HpiSoapFault
              ->Error 
              ->Code;
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly!